# condition for orthonormal vector set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \{u_1, u_2, \ldots , u_k \} $ be $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that this family is an orthonormal family if and only if the matrix
${u_1}{u_1}^T + {u_2}{u_2}^T + \cdots + {u_k}{u_k}^T$ is a projection.

Can anyone guide me through this problem? I really need help!

Comment: What have you got as a definition of a projection?

Comment: Well, actually an *orthogonal* projection.

Comment: $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ and $P^2 = P = P^T$ right?

Comment: $$(\sum_{i = 1}^nu_iu_i^T)(\sum_{i = 1}^nu_iu_i^T) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^nu_i(u_i^Tu_j)u_j^T = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n\delta_{ij}u_iu_j^T = \sum_{i = 1}^nu_iu_i^T.$$

Comment: @SecretMath how would you apply that to prove orthonormality?

Comment: @AlexR can you guys tell me why $[u_1u_1^T + u_2u_x^T + \cdots + u_ku_k^T]$ is a matrix first?

Comment: or @AlgebraicPavel can you tell me why it is a matrix? shouldn't it be [1+1+1$\cdots$] if set of $u$ is orthonormal vectors?

Comment: Well, $vv^T$ is a rank-$1$ matrix, and this is a sum of such
@Mark notice $v$ is to be considered a column vector (i.e. $n\times 1$-matrix)
$$uu^T \neq u^Tu$$

Comment: @AlexR So if the vector set is orthonormal, than the matrix would be $1 \times k$ looks like $[1 1 1 \cdots]$?

Comment: @Mark nope, look again. $uu^T \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: @AlexR so the matrix will be $k \times k$ $I$ here right?

Comment: @Mark reconsider Matrix multiplication and summation. The result will be a $n\times n$ matrix and a _sum_ of $k \quad n\times n$ matrices each of rank $1$.

Comment: @AlexR got it, since the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: is it gonna be identity matrix though?

Comment: @Mark I am still trying to prove the other direction, otherwise I will just write an answer.

Comment: @SecretMath won't work, chose $u_k = 0\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1} \quad \forall\ k$, then $0\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is the sum and is idempotent (i.e. a projection).

Comment: @SecretMath so you wrote that if the vector set is orthonormal than the given matrix is indeed projection right?

Comment: @AlexR You can't take $0$ vector as a counterexample.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I proved only one direction.

Comment: @SecretMath Why? Given only the conditions above, $u_k$ need not be pairwise different...

Comment: @Mark And the other direction is probably wrong. Take $u_1 = u_2 = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$. Try to add linear independence to your family of vectors.

Comment: @AlexR Yea you can, but I am trying to enhance the condition to make it equivalent.

Comment: Well, they must be linearly independent, otherwise they could not be orthonormal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, assume that $k\leq n$ since any orthonormal set of vectors must be linearly independent as well.

Let $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ be orthonormal, that is, $u_i^Tu_j=\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol. Note that the sum $u_1u_1^T+\cdots+u_ku_k^T$ can be written as $UU^T$, where $U=[u_1,\ldots,u_k]$ is the $n\times k$ matrix such that the $i$th column of $U$ is $u_i$. Then $P=u_1u_1^T+\cdots+u_ku_k^T=UU^T$ is an orthogonal projection because: 1) $P$ is symmetric ($P^T=(UU^T)^T=(U^T)^TU^T=UU^T=P$) and idempotent ($P^2=(UU^T)(UU^T)=U(U^TU)U^T=U(I)U^T=UU^T=P$; note that $U^TU$ is equal to the identity because $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ are orthonormal).

Now assume that $P=UU^T$ is an orthonormal projection and $U$ has rank $k$ (that is, $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ are linearly independent). We have $P^T=P$ (trivially satisfied for any $U$) and $P^2=P$, that is, $U(U^TU)U^T=UU^T$. We need to show that this implies that $U^TU=I$ (and, equivalently, $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ are orthonormal). There might be a more elementary way but one using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization works just fine. Since $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ has rank $k$, there is an orthonormal matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ and a nonsingular upper triangular matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ with positive diagonal entries such that $U=QR$. Since $U(U^TU)U^T=UU^T$, we have $QR(R^TQ^TQR)R^TQ^T=QRR^TQ^T$. But $Q^TQ=I$ ($Q$ has orthonormal columns) so we have $QR(R^TR)R^TQ^T=QR^TRQ^T$. Pre-multiplying with $Q^T$ and post-multiplying with $Q$ gives (for the same reasons) $R(R^TR)R^T=RR^T$, which gives $R^TR=I$ (multiply by $R^{-1}$ and $R^{-T}$ respectively from left and right). Now try to show that $R^TR=I$ implies that $R=I$ (note that $R$ is a nonsingular triangular matrix with positive diagonal entries). Well but since $R=I$, then $U=Q$ and therefore $U$ has orthonormal columns.

The condition on the linear independence of $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ to show the other implication is important as shows the example given by Secret Math.

P.S.:

1) As said in the comments, $u_iu_i^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix (well, $u_i$ is actually an $n\times 1$ "matrix", so by the definition of the matrix multiplication, what is $u_iu_i^T$?).

2) The simplest way to see that $u_1u_1^T+\cdots+u_ku_k^T=UU^T$ is to use $I=\sum_{i=1}^ke_ie_i^T$, where $I$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix, $e_i$ is the $i$th vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, the zero $n$-vector with $1$ in the $i$th entry. Next thing is to realize that the matrix-vector product $Ue_i$ is equal to the $i$th column of $U$, that is, $Ue_i=u_i$. Hence
$$
UU^T=U(I)U^T=U\left(\sum_{i=1}^ke_ie_i^T\right)U^T
=\sum_{i=1}^k(Ue_i)(e_i^TU^T)
=\sum_{i=1}^k(Ue_i)(Ue_i)^T
=\sum_{i=1}^ku_iu_i^T.
$$

3) Matrices are your friends, same as [matrix factorizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition).